# How to upgrade/update opam to its latest version

Tags: ocaml, upgrade, opam

Obviously, `opam upgrade` doesn't work because it's for the installed packages only, not for opam itself.

The first link in the Google search is [deprecated](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Upgrade_guide.html) and doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest doc describes it in [this part of the documentation](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html).

You just have to run this command in your console :

```
bash -c "sh <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)"
```

This works on

```
Linux (amd64, arm64, arm7, i686)
macOS (amd64, arm64)
FreeBSD (amd64)
OpenBSD (amd64)
```

Comment: This only works if it is also how you installed it in the first place. You should generally prefer to use a system package manager, such as the one included in pretty much every Linux distribution. This is also what the documentation you link to states, "This is generally the recommended way, when available and up-to-date ". The problem of updating opam is then delegated to the package manager, as with any other piece of software installed in that manner.